# Погребли ее там же (,) вместе с дочерьми. Какова роль запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, семантика, смысл

Дочерей похоронили на высоком холме. Мать преставилась вчера. Погребли ее там же (,) вместе с дочерьми.

- Смысл последнего предложения такой: мать похоронили в том месте, где погребены дочери. Контекстом он подсказывается. Как повлияет запятая на смысл предложения? Вызовет двусмысленность, вроде: погребали одновременно с дочерьми? Возникает ли двусмысленность при отсутствии запятой?

Comment: Слово "вместе" вводит в заблуждение. Оно может быть применено, если их похоронили в одной могиле или одновременно. Лучше сказать "рядом".

Comment: А если употребить слово "рядом", нужна ли запятая перед ним?

Comment: Думаю, нужна. Это уточнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Погребли её там же,** (где именно?) **вместе с дочерьми.**

Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства места и времени, поскольку именно они могут обозначаться обобщённо и неопределённо (там, туда, оттуда; везде, всюду; тогда, потом и др.). Конкретику даёт именно уточняющий член.
Уточняющий член предложения [*вместе с дочерьми*] следует за уточняемым [*там же*], поэтому ставится запятая.
Если используется наречие "рядом", то запятая также нужна.

[**Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724)

["Вместе с дочерьми" тоже возможно, если имеется в виду, допустим, родовой склеп на высоком холме.
Можно использовать и другие, подходящие по смыслу и не вызывающие дополнительных вопросов, наречия: около, возле, рядышком, подле.]